# How do I make an object that works like an enum of enums (a 2D enum) in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, enums

I'm trying to convert a one-dimensional enum to a two-dimensional one. So instead of:

```js
import FEATURES from 'enums/features'
if (isEnabled(FEATURES.ALLOW_FILTERING)) { ... }
if (isEnabled(FEATURES.HIGHLIGHT_ROWS)) { ... }
if (isEnabled(FEATURES.NEW_SIGNUP_FORM)) { ... }
```

I want to do this:

```js
import FEATURES from 'enums/features'
if (isEnabled(FEATURES.TABLES.ALLOW_FILTERING)) { ... }
if (isEnabled(FEATURES.TABLES.HIGHLIGHT_ROWS)) { ... }
if (isEnabled(FEATURES.ONBOARDING.NEW_SIGNUP_FORM)) { ... }
```

Of course, TypeScript doesn't support actual two-dimensional enums. What other data structure can I use to accomplish the syntax above? Strong typing is a must.

Comment: Docs only mention numeric or string values for enums https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Comment: How would that be different form the one dimensional `TABLES_ALLOW_FILTERING`, `TABLES_HIGHLIGHT_ROWS`, ...

Comment: @zerkms Thanks, I edited the question to make it clear that I'm just looking for a pattern that _works_ like a two-dimensional enum.

Comment: @Henry A "2D enum" would be easier to browse when using autocomplete, and easier to split into multiple files if any of the top-level categories gets too big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use several enums and put them in a single namespace. You can then also declare a type alias that is a union of all enums with the same name as the namespace:

```
export namespace FEATURES {
    export enum TABLES {
        ALLOW_FILTERING,
        HIGHLIGHT_ROWS
    }
    export enum ONBOARDING {
        NEW_SIGNUP_FORM
    }
}

export type FEATURES  = FEATURES.ONBOARDING | FEATURES.TABLES

function isEnabled(v: FEATURES) : boolean { return true }


if (isEnabled(FEATURES.TABLES.ALLOW_FILTERING)) {  }
if (isEnabled(FEATURES.TABLES.HIGHLIGHT_ROWS)) {  }
if (isEnabled(FEATURES.ONBOARDING.NEW_SIGNUP_FORM)) {  }
```